# How to open Excel data or files directly to Gridview

Tags: excel, vb.net

The next step is similar of import Excel files, but this time is open files directly to the folder, without opening or selecting files to the window, only clicking the button.

Importing all Excel files directly into GridView:

[image: Importing all Excel files directly into GridView]

This is the Example of code:

```
  Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim mainDts As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim Excel As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\Tests\Test"
    OpenFileDialog.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Xls Files (*.xls)|*.xls"
    If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each fileName As String In OpenFileDialog.FileNames
            Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(fileName)
            Excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet$]")

            conn.Close()
            If mainDts Is Nothing Then
                mainDts = dts
            Else
                mainDts.Merge(dts)
            End If
        Next
        GridControl1.DataSource = mainDts
        GridControl1.DataMember = "[Sheet$]"
    End If

End Sub
```

Can it Import just clicking this button to open directly files like this?

```
"C:\Tests\Test"
```

Comment: Sure.  As long as you specify a valid path and file name in the Excel variable.

Comment: Remove the `OpenFileDialog` and replace it with whatever logic you need to get the filename.

Comment: @djv how, like this with filename? `C:\Tests\Test\Test1.xls`

Comment: @BrianMStafford like these files? `Test1.xls\Test2.xls\Test3.xls\`?

Comment: No, just like you have in the comment for @djv.

Comment: using with this? `InitialDirectory = "C:\Tests\Test\Test1.xls"` ? @BrianMStafford

Comment: If you remove the `OpenFileDialog`, then there will be no `InitialDirectory`, so no

Comment: @djv just only opening this? `InitialDirectory = "C:\Tests\Test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the OpenFileDialog, and replace its FileNames property with your own FileNames collection. In this case I made a simple array on the spot.

```
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim mainDts As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim Excel As String
    Dim fileNames = {"C:\Tests\Test\Test1.xls"}
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(fileName)
        Excel = fi.FullName
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet$]", conn)
        dts = New DataSet
        dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet$]")
        conn.Close()
        If mainDts Is Nothing Then
            mainDts = dts
        Else
            mainDts.Merge(dts)
        End If
    Next
    GridControl1.DataSource = mainDts
    GridControl1.DataMember = "[Sheet$]"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can it use with two or all files like this? `C:\Tests\Test\Test1.xls\Test2.xls\Test3.xls`

Comment: or just open only once?

Comment: @Fopa Just put the other filenames in the array `Dim fileNames = {"C:\Tests\Test\Test1.xls"}`

Comment: I will post the question about the progress

Comment: @Fopa For example `Dim fileNames = {"C:\Tests\Test\Test1.xls", "C:\Tests\Test\Test2.xls", "C:\Tests\Test\Test3.xls"}`

Comment: let me check, because I don't know if will include the `Multiselect`

Comment: So, you use `FileInfo` to get `FullName` while *at the same time* the variable `fileName`  *is* full name of the file? Am I right?

Comment: I'm not going to fix other things. I just did what I initially said in my comment: *Remove the `OpenFileDialog` and replace it with whatever logic you need to get the filename.*